# Using ODBC to access a SQL server on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc

I'm maintaining a legacy desktop environment for Windows written in C/C++. It uses ODBC to access SQL Server (and PostgreSQL among others). One of the users are currently in the process of moving his production database to Azure. Everything seems normal after switching the driver connect to the Azure db using:

```
DRIVER=ODBC driver 17 for SQL server;SERVER=tcp:<database>.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=<My database>;ENCRYPT=yes;TRUSTSERVERCERTIFICATE=no;Connection Timeout=60;ConnectionRetryCount=5
```

The problem occurs after the program has been idle for some time (20 minutes approx). When accessing the connection, ODBC throws an error saying the connection has been terminated at the server. We have seen this also on AWS using PostgreSQL, and solved the issue using the "KeepAlive" parameter in the PostgreSQL ODBC driver. I have found articles from Microsoft about "KeepAlive" for their "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", but I do not get it to work. No matter what and how I try to append the "KeepAlive=50;KeepAliveInterval=10" to the connection string, it makes no difference. To me it seems like they are only there for linux/mac??

The connection to the db is standard:

```
dbStatus=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &EnvHandle);
dbStatus=SQLSetEnvAttr(EnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3_80 , 0);
dbStatus=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, EnvHandle, &hdbc);
//connection setting..
result = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc,NULL,(UCHAR *)conStr,inLen,(UCHAR *)rConStr,MAX_DC_LEN, &rConLen, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE_REQUIRED);
```

After successful connect using SQLDriverConnect(), I'm checking the ConnectionRetryCount and ConnectionRetryInterval by:

```
SQLGetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECT_RETRY_COUNT, &i, SQL_IS_INTEGER, NULL);
SQLGetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECT_RETRY_INTERVAL, &i, SQL_IS_INTEGER, NULL);
```

They (i) always have the same values of 1 and 10.

We are using prepared statements and cursors.
Running a test where I ask for a cursor to all rows in a table ("select col1,col2 from tab1"), and each minute ask for the next row, I've held the db connection open 24 hours before I closed the client.

Are there any hints and/or tricks to keep an idle SQL Server ODBC session alive when using Azure? I'm 100% sure there is, since using PostgreSQL on AWS it works flawless. I currently trying to add C/C++ code to handle this, but have so far not succeeded. Any hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no KeepAlive option in ODBC Driver for SQL Server.

You need to use **Connection Retry Interval** and **Connection Retry Count** features to keep your connection active.

In the connection string shared by you, **you are passing `ConnectionRetryCount` parameter, which is wrong.** You need to **pass `ConnectRetryCount` parameter and pass the values range from 0 to 255**. Zero (0) means don't attempt to reconnect. The default value is one reconnection attempt.

To pass connect retry interval, use `ConnectRetryInterval` parameter. `ConnectRetryInterval` adds a wait time between each `ConnectRetryCount` attempt.  Its range is from 1 (default) to 60 seconds and it’s applied after the first reconnection attempt:

- When a broken connection is detected, the client immediately attempts to reconnect (this is the first reconnection attempt and only occurs if ConnectRetryCount > 0);
- If the first reconnection attempt fails, and ConnectRetryCount > 1, then the client waits ConnectRetryInterval in order to try the second and subsequent reconnection attempts;
- The amount of time needed for the reconnection process cannot exceed the value of the command timeout. So, the command timeout must be greater than or equal to the total reconnection time (ConnectRetryCount * ConnectRetryInterval).

Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/connection-resiliency?view=sql-server-ver15 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the syntax error! Embarrassing to not notice. But sadly it do not help. When syntax is correct like "ConnectRetryCount=5;ConnectRetryInterval=5", I get the correct values back from the "SQLGetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECT_RETRY_COUNT..", but my connection is being closed after a relative short idle time.

Comment: which sql server you are using?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. I'm just given access to a endpoint, but the server identifies itself as "SQL Server 12.0.2000.8"

Comment: Please note: The connection resiliency feature is supported on Microsoft Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2014 (and later) server versions. The feature is available on Windows starting with Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. It is available on Linux starting in version 17.2 of Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

Comment: I have been informed that this is a Microsoft Azure SQL Database (12.0.2000.8), and we are using 17.8 of the Odbc driver. According to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-ver15) the KeepAlive is supported for all platforms (LMW), From what I read everything is correct in the setup, but it does not behave as wanted.

Comment: But as per the link shared in the answer, connection resiliency feature is not supported for every server.

Comment: Thanks. Since I as vendor of the tool do not control the setup users/customers/developers are using on their servers, I've added a test whenever the connection is to be used.
Status = SQLGetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECTION_DEAD, &conAttrDead, conAttrLen, NULL);
If the conAttrDead equals SQL_CD_TRUE I know the connection is broken, and free all resources connected to HDBC, and do a re-connect. 
It is a very expensive function to use, so currently I do this depending on a setting the user/customer adds to the config of my tool.